# Problema de redireccionamiento con .htaccess en linux

Tags: php, html, linux, windows, apache

Estoy realizando la construcción de una página web utilizando el patron mvc.
Mi proyecto tiene una carpeta raíz llamada Miranda y 2 subcarpetas llamadas app (acá se encuentran los controladores y la parte lógica de la pagina) y public_html (acá se encuentran los recursos).

Cada carpeta tiene un archivo `.htaccess` respectivamente. La cuestión es que en windows me funciona perfectamente pero en Arch Linux no lee el `.htaccess` de la carpeta raíz (el de las carpeta `app` y `public_html` sí los lee) y como consecuencia me muestra el index de apache.

Archivo .htaccess de la carpeta raíz:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$ public_html/Paginas [L]

RewriteRule (.*) public_html/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el código del `.htaccess` para saber lo que está fallando.

Comment: Ya solucioné el problema, debía habilitar el "LoadModule rewrite_module ..." en las configuraciones del apache.